# LDAP doesn't work with port 389/3268

Tags: jsp, ldap

When using LDAP connection with port 389/3268 using JSP it raises the following exception:
**javax.naming.CommunicationException:XXX.XXX.ROOT:389[Root exception is java.net.ConnectionException:Connection timed out : connect]**

**Main Problem:** This error occurs very randomly, once it starts working it works fine, else it will give he exception

How can the problem be resolved ???

Thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: I would say you have a connection leak somewhere. Make sure you're closing every `Context` and `NamingEnumeration' in your code, in `finally` blocks so it cannot be bypassed in each case.

Comment: Even though the changes were made the same issue comes up again...